# flink-sql: how do check if the array type contains the given element?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

I am trying to check if a given string is present in an array of strings

Is there flink-SQL support for this operation?

In other words, I am looking the flink SQL equivalent for prestoSQL's `contains()` array function([prestodb docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/array.html#array-functions))

Answer (score 0):

Maybe with `UNNEST`? In this example from the Flink docs, tags is an array:

```sql
SELECT users, tag
FROM Orders CROSS JOIN UNNEST(tags) AS t (tag)
```